# (Python, IDLE, Windows) Pressing Stack Viewer exits all IDLE windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, python-3.x, python-idle

I am running Python 3.1.2 with IDLE 3.1.2 on Windows 7. When I try to use the Stack Viewer, blue text and a new window briefly appear before all open IDLE windows exit (I don't have time to read the text or new window). This is the first time I have used Stack Viewer.

Is this normal behavior? How can I get the Stack Viewer to stay open?

Thanks for your help,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

This IDLE bug (3 series only) was fixed 30Jan11.  The fix is in 3.1.4 and 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html), the stack viewer shows the stack traceback of the last exception. So maybe in your case, you are trying to open the stack viewer, without any exception haven taken place?

```
>>> a

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

If you type 'a' and press ENTER, an exception occurs. Now try opening the stack viewer?

Comment: It crashes. I can press the Stack Viewer button before an exception and nothing happens, and I can turn on Auto Open Stack Viewer. But when I try to use it when an exception has occurred (or it auto opens), IDLE crashes.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly call Stack Viewer after an exception occurs. (Auto Open set to False)

Comment: IDLE briefly opens a new window, then all IDLE windows exit before I can read what it says.

Comment: Uhm, ok. Sorry can't help you more than this. Sounds n00bish, but maybe try a re-install? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows so I can't help you with hands-on experience, but I would do the following:

- see what is the exact command that runs when you click on the menu item for Idle (I think you can right-click and see its properties, or at least you could on earlier versions of Windows)
- open a command prompt, and run the command that opens Idle
- open the stack viewer and then note the traceback that (should!) appear in the command prompt window
- report said traceback here :)

BTW, in my installation (neither Windows nor Python 3.x), an attempt to open the stack viewer without a traceback produces the following message box:

- Title: No stack trace
- Message: There is no stack trace yet.
  (sys.last_traceback is not defined)

Comment: When I opened idle.py in Lib\idlelib, forced an exception, and used stack view IDLE stayed open. This appeared in the command prompt:

C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib>python idle.py
*** Internal Error: rpc.py:SocketIO.localcall()

 Object: 45342064
 Method: <bound method WrappedObjectTreeItem._GetSubList of <idlelib.RemoteObjec
tBrowser.WrappedObjectTreeItem object at 0x02B3DD70>>
 Args: ()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python31\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 188, in localcall
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python31\lib\idlelib\RemoteObjectBrowser.py", line 21, in _GetSubList

Comment: return list(map(remote_object_tree_item, list))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1171, in open_stack_viewer
    return self.interp.remote_stack_viewer()
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 572, in remote_stack_viewer
    node.expand()
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\TreeWidget.py", line 131, in expand
    self.update()

Comment: File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\TreeWidget.py", line 170, in update
    self.draw(7, 2)
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\TreeWidget.py", line 184, in draw
    sublist = self.item._GetSubList()
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\RemoteObjectBrowser.py", line 36, in _GetSubList

    return [StubObjectTreeItem(self.sockio, oid) for oid in list]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

It also works when I just mouse open idle.py, but not when I open python.pyw. I suspect the IDLE shortcut points to idle.pyw